# Find a combination of numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to check if an incoming numerical array matches any variation of a set of numerical arrays. I am basically just stuck on the logic.

Given

```
var myData = [1, 201, 100]
```

Are these three numbers found in any order in the following pre-set combinations

```
var combo1 = [1, 100, 200]
var combo2 = [1, 101, 201]
var combo3 = [1, 100, 201]
var combo4 = [1, 101, 200];
```

My attempt so far is going nowhere so I've reduced it to this
https://jsfiddle.net/0mvk9dj4/1/

```
var myData = [1, 201, 100];

var combo1 = [1, 100, 200]
var combo2 = [1, 101, 201]
var combo3 = [1, 100, 201]
var combo4 = [1, 101, 200];
var combos = [combo1, combo2, combo3, combo4];

function findCombo(data) {
  var found = false
  for (var i = 0; i < combos.length; i++) {
    var combo = combos[i];
    for (var x = 0; x < combo.length; x++) {
      for (var y = 0; y < data.length; y++) {
        if (data[y] === combo[x]) {
          found = true;
          break;
        } else {
          found = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("Found? " + found)
  return found;
}

findCombo(myData);
```

Comment: Are combo1-4 fix, i.e. not subject to change during code execution?

Comment: Indeed they are fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `findCombo` function in the code below uses a functional approach to solve your problem. Feel free to read more about the [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) methods on the Mozilla Developer Network.

```
var myData = [1, 201, 100];

var combo1 = [1, 100, 200];
var combo2 = [1, 101, 201];
var combo3 = [1, 100, 201];
var combo4 = [1, 101, 200];

var combos = [combo1, combo2, combo3, combo4];

function findCombo(data, combos) {
  return combos.some(function(combo) {
    return combo.every((item) => data.includes(item));
  });
}

console.log(findCombo(myData, combos));
```

Comment: I found this to be the fastest of the answers. Thanks! https://jsperf.com/array-combo-check/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.findIndex()` or `.filter()`, `.every()`, `.some()`

```js
var myData = [1, 201, 100];

var combo1 = [1, 100, 200]
var combo2 = [1, 101, 201]
var combo3 = [1, 100, 201]
var combo4 = [1, 101, 200];
var combos = [combo1, combo2, combo3, combo4];
var res = combos.filter(combo =>  combo.every(n => myData.some(curr => curr === n)));

console.log(res);

var res = combos.findIndex(combo =>  combo.every(n => myData.some(curr => curr === n)));

console.log(combos[res]);
```

Comment: `myData` is the input to be tested, so wouldn't it be something like `myData.every(n => combos.some(combo => combo.includes(n)))`?

Comment: @nnnnnn Not presently at computer where can check for certain. Approach at Answer should return index of matching array within combos array

Comment: Maybe we're just approaching the same thing from opposite angles. I put the `.every()` on `myData` because I was thinking of it as "every element of `myData` is in [one of the combos]", but all of the arrays are the same length so doing it the opposite way is probably fine. Though now that I look at it I think my logic is faulty in that it probably is checking that each element in `myData` is in *some* array, not all in the same array.